# What protocol uses nginx when proxying requests to frontend service?

Tags: http, nginx, tcp, server, proxy

Suppose, we have Angular application (or another frontend framework) running on a server on localhost:4000.
And we have nginx proxying user requests to this application.

Which protocol nginx using for transporting data ? http? or TCP ? or another ?

In case of PHP application(backend) I know that communication happens via: 
nginx - fastcgi - php-fpm

But what about another languages?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model). TCP is the transport layer, http is the application layer. So  http + tcp is the default. Sometimes you can see unix sockets instead, which are much faster than TCP if the applications resides both on the same hardware machine.